# Converting Excel, PowerPoint, PDF, and Word to Images in .NET using Aspose

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, aspose

so I am looking for a way to convert  Excel, PowerPoint, PDF, and Word to Images. I was wondering if anyone has experience with the Aspose suite and knows if all of this can be done with the Aspose.PDF suite, or would I need to get Aspose.slides, and Aspose.word as well?

Comment: why not put this question directly in aspose forum?

Comment: I E-mailed support, sometimes I get faster responses on here though. Which worked well since I found out about the Web API :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need Aspose.Slides, Aspose.Words, Aspose.Cells and Aspose.Pdf or you can use [Web Api](http://saaspose.com/docs/dashboard.action)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Web API, cheaper without all the extra Aspose functionality that my project really doesn't need.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion from office document to image could be done without using any third party component. Below code will convert specific range from an Excel worksheet to Image, for example.

IMPORTANT: Don't forget to mark the method with [STAThread] attribute.

Usings:

```
    using xls = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Conversion Code:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileNameToProcess = @"D:\Book2.xlsx";

        //Start Excel and create a new document.
        xls.Application oExcel = new xls.Application();
        xls.Workbook wb = null;
        try
        {
            wb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(
                fileNameToProcess.ToString(), false, false, Type.Missing, "", "", true, xls.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", false, false, 0, false, true, 0);
            //wb.RefreshAll();

            xls.Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets as xls.Sheets;
            xls.Worksheet sheet = sheets[1];

            //Following is used to find range with data
            string startRange = "A1";
            string endRange = "P25";
            xls.Range range = sheet.get_Range(startRange, endRange);
            range.CopyPicture(xls.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, xls.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);

            System.Drawing.Image imgRange = GetImageFromClipboard();

            imgRange.Save(@"d:\ExcelSheetImage.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            wb.Save();
            Console.Write("Specified range converted to image successfully. Press Enter to continue.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            //throw;
        }
        finally 
        {
            wb.Close();
            oExcel.Quit();
            oExcel = null;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static System.Drawing.Image GetImageFromClipboard()
    {
        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = null;

        // This doesn't work
        //if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
        //{
        //    returnImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
        //}
        //return returnImage;

        // This works
        System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject d = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (d.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            returnImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
        }

        return returnImage;
    }
```

Comment: I'll check this out, I spent several days researching a way to do this using Interop, and was unable to do so. I asked this question a while ago, so I already coded everything, but its only the demo version and nothing was purchased yet, so not too late to change.

Answer (score 1):

My name is Nayyer and I am working as developer evangelist at Aspose.

- Aspose.Words is provides the feature to create/manipulate MS word
  documents and it also offers the feature to convert word documents
  into Image format. You may check following link for more details on
  [convert MS Word document to Image](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Convert+a+Document+to+PDF) (simply select Jpeg, Png, Bmp
  from SaveFormat enumeration).
- Similarly you can use Aspose.Cells to convert Excel worksheets into Image format. [Converting worksheet into Image](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Converting+Worksheet+to+Image)
- Aspose.Slides can be used to convert PowerPoint
  presentations to Image format. [Create Thumbnail image of slide](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Creating+Slide+Thumbnail+Image).
- Aspose.Pdf supports the feature to transform PDF pages into Image
  format. For further details, please visit [Convert all PDF pages to
  JPEG format](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Convert+all+PDF+pages+to+JPEG+Images).

Comment: The PowerPoint tutorial has moved to http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Creating+Slides+Thumbnail+Image

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 2019, but if anyone is still wondering, you can do this using Aspose.Words.

The following values (and more) in the SaveFormat enum are available:

```
    Tiff = 100,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Renders a page of the document and saves it as a PNG file.
    Png = 101,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Renders a page of the document and saves it as a BMP file.
    Bmp = 102,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Renders a page of the document and saves it as a JPEG file.
    Jpeg = 104,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Renders a page of the document and saves it as a GIF file.
    Gif = 105
```

You would use them like so:

```
    var fileContents = asposeDocument.GenerateDocument(Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Png);
```